Why does APT gives priority to a higher version of a package?
I am working with ROS, Ubuntu 22 in Jetson board. I have been facing a problem that I think is related to my system's package management, that is why I came here asking for help.
When I compile a ROS package I see an error related to CMAKE (files that are automatically generated/installed on my machine):
Starting >>> realsense2_camera
--- stderr: realsense2_camera                         
CMake Error at /usr/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules.cmake:172 (message):
  The imported target "opencv_core" references the file

     "/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.8.0"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  /opt/ros/humble/share/cv_bridge/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/humble/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridgeConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:107 (find_package)


---
Failed   <<< realsense2_camera [0.57s, exited with code 1]

So there is a reference to a shared library version 4.8.0 that does not exist. I then proceed to check which packages are installed on my Ubuntu:
dpkg -l | grep opencv
ii  libopencv-calib3d4.5d:arm64                        4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision Camera Calibration library
ii  libopencv-contrib4.5d:arm64                        4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision contrlib library
ii  libopencv-core4.5d:arm64                           4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision core library
ii  libopencv-dev                                      4.8.0-1-g6371ee1                                  arm64        Open Computer Vision Library
ii  libopencv-dnn4.5d:arm64                            4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision Deep neural network module
ii  libopencv-features2d4.5d:arm64                     4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision Feature Detection and Descriptor Extraction library
ii  libopencv-flann4.5d:arm64                          4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision Clustering and Search in Multi-Dimensional spaces library
ii  libopencv-highgui4.5d:arm64                        4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision High-level GUI and Media I/O library
ii  libopencv-imgcodecs4.5d:arm64                      4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision Image Codecs library
ii  libopencv-imgproc4.5d:arm64                        4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision Image Processing library
ii  libopencv-ml4.5d:arm64                             4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision Machine Learning library
ii  libopencv-objdetect4.5d:arm64                      4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision Object Detection library
ii  libopencv-photo4.5d:arm64                          4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision computational photography library
ii  libopencv-shape4.5d:arm64                          4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision shape descriptors and matchers library
ii  libopencv-stitching4.5d:arm64                      4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision image stitching library
ii  libopencv-video4.5d:arm64                          4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision Video analysis library
ii  libopencv-videoio4.5d:arm64                        4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision Video I/O library
ii  libopencv-viz4.5d:arm64                            4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        computer vision 3D data visualization library
ii  python3-opencv:arm64                               4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4                               arm64        Python 3 bindings for the computer vision library
ii  ros-humble-vision-opencv                           3.2.1-1jammy.20240731.052303                      arm64        Packages for interfacing ROS2 with OpenCV, a library of programming functions for real time computer vision.

Crazy! The only component that my ROS package requires is installed with a higher version than the rest. I checked and all packages that have been automatically installed on my workstation are version 4.5. Weird! I reinstalled ROS on my Jetson using apt and nothing changes, I am still getting the same inconsistency.
I uninstalled ROS (the package that installs libopencv-dev) and I try some aptitude commands:
$ aptitude why libopencv-dev
Not currently installed
The candidate version 4.8.0-1-g6371ee1 has priority optional
No dependencies require to install libopencv-dev

$ aptitude versions libopencv-dev
p   4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4       jammy                  500 
p   4.8.0-1-g6371ee1          stable                 600

Weird! The package is not installed but version 4.8 has a priority, and version 4.5.4, the one that I need, is available!
So my question is, how do I remove priority of version 4.8 over 4.5? Am I on the right track?
Thanks in advance,

why would apt not give priority to a higher version? you need to tell apt to ignore it and that is called pinning. Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

I understand what you mean, I do updates on my system all the time. I double checked everything, turns out my installation is broken. All symbolic links libraries under /usr/lib/libopencv*

are broken, not eve the SO files are present. Symbolic link libopencv_core.so.4.8.0 points to nothing, the libraries are installed under /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu, not under /usr/lib. I started changing all symbolic links one by one and the compilation error changed as I created valid symbolic links. Unfortunately there is missing library in my installation and I cannot create one symbolic link. Suggestions?
